# Predicting future data using a single column as input data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, statsmodels

I am having trouble with predicting future values with my input set. I am fairly new with statsmodels so I am not sure if it is even possible to do with this much input data.

This is the DataFrame that I am using. (Note: Starts at index 5 since I had to filter some data)

```
    year  suicides_no
5   1990       193361
6   1991       198020
7   1992       211473
8   1993       221565
9   1994       232063
10  1995       243544
11  1996       246725
12  1997       240745
13  1998       249591
14  1999       256119
15  2000       255832
16  2001       250652
17  2002       256095
18  2003       256079
19  2004       240861
20  2005       234375
21  2006       233361
22  2007       233408
23  2008       235447
24  2009       243487
25  2010       238702
26  2011       236484
27  2012       230160
28  2013       223199
29  2014       222984
30  2015       203640
```

[image]

From this, id like to get a prediction for the years (2016-2022) and plot it to a graph like this one.

Comment: Can you give more context on the task? This is a much more difficult problem than you’re anticipating, and any method you choose won’t work well on this data. The real answer is that any reasonable forecast needs much more information. The only value of forecasting from this data using statsmodels would be to demonstrate why they (and the data) aren’t sufficient for this task.

Comment: at least I would take population into account and for example look at suicide rates instead of total count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather open-ended problem. I can certainly show you how you might write some code to make **a** prediction, but I think discussing how to make a **good** prediction is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. It will be very dependent on a good understanding of the problem domain.

But with that caveat aside, on with the show. You've suggested you'd like to see a Statsmodel example.

[Statsmodels is certainly capable of these sorts of forecasts.](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/tsa.html) There are lots of approaches but yes, you can take a 1D time-series and use it to make future predictions.

[There's also a detailed tutorial of state space models here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html) - this is a common approach, or rather, family of approaches. Different state-space models would be used depending on e.g. whether you feel seasonality (cyclic behaviour), or certain exogenous variables (contextual drivers of behaviour) are important or not.

I adapted a simple example from there:

```py
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels as sm

# df = your DataFrame

endog = df.suicides_number
endog.index = pd.period_range("1990", "2015", freq="Y") 

# Construct the (very simple) AR model
mod = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(endog, order=(1, 0, 0), trend='c')

# Estimate the parameters
res = mod.fit()

res.forecast(steps=7)
```

The `order` parameter determines exactly what sort of model you get. This is pretty simple, an autoregression model that looks at past behaviour, recent behaviour, and extrapolates forward.

As I said, I cannot guarantee it will give you a good forecast here (it's definitely a reach to take 25 samples forward to predict the next 7), but you could test different parameters and read up on this type of model.

Comment: How would I plot the following forecast into a line plot with the current data points like the graph above?

Comment: I believe using `order=(1,0,0)` reduces it to simple AR. The `sm.tsa.SARIMAX` class semantics essentially treats ARIMA etc as special cases of the SARIMAX model. I indicated this in the comment, while providing that OP might extend it. For example, they might find some exogenous values that will make this tractable. I think I was fairly clear that this is a code demonstration, not modeling advice.

Comment: @ImprovedEngineer `res.forecast(steps=7).plot()`, but if you take a look at the linked tutorial you will see several examples of plotting code (including plots of uncertainty ranges). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thats great, thank you! I am aware that this prediction is very inaccurate due to the lack of data input but for the sake of what I am doing with this prediction, it will be fine.

Comment: Great - I assume you were looking for a gentle introduction to this area using some simple data. As long as you're not trying to build a model anyone's going to try to sell to customers, or rely on in any way to be accurate, I say fill your boots.